# Count rows before event - data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset, with users and sequential events and non-events inbetween.

```
DT = data.table(user = c("1001","1001","1001","1001","1001","1001",
                          "1002","1002","1002","1002"), 
               event = c(NA,"e1",NA,NA,NA,"e2",
                           "e1",NA,NA,"e2"))
```

I want to be able to count the rows(non-events) before an event occurs by user group. Expected result:

```
   user  event  rows.before.event
 1: 1001    NA                 NA
 2: 1001    e1                  1
 3: 1001    NA                 NA
 4: 1001    NA                 NA
 5: 1001    NA                 NA
 6: 1001    e2                  3
 7: 1002    e1                  0
 8: 1002    NA                 NA
 9: 1002    NA                 NA
10: 1002    e2                  2
```

Have tried with `rleid()` but no success. Any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DT[, count := .N-1, by = .(user, rev(cumsum(rev(!is.na(event)))))][
   is.na(event), count := NA]
#    user event count
# 1: 1001    NA    NA
# 2: 1001    e1     1
# 3: 1001    NA    NA
# 4: 1001    NA    NA
# 5: 1001    NA    NA
# 6: 1001    e2     3
# 7: 1002    e1     0
# 8: 1002    NA    NA
# 9: 1002    NA    NA
#10: 1002    e2     2
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you @eddi I had never seen rev() :)

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `rleid` and `shift`:

```
DT[, before := .N, by = .(user, rleid(is.na(event)))
   ][, before := shift(before, fill = 0), by = user
     ][is.na(event), before := NA][]
```

which gives:

```
    user event before
 1: 1001    NA     NA
 2: 1001    e1      1
 3: 1001    NA     NA
 4: 1001    NA     NA
 5: 1001    NA     NA
 6: 1001    e2      3
 7: 1002    e1      0
 8: 1002    NA     NA
 9: 1002    NA     NA
10: 1002    e2      2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> DT[, rows.before.event:=  ifelse(is.na(event), NA, .N - 1) ,by = list(user, c(0, cumsum(!is.na(event))[-length(event)]))]
> DT
    user event rows.before.event
 1: 1001    NA                NA
 2: 1001    e1                 1
 3: 1001    NA                NA
 4: 1001    NA                NA
 5: 1001    NA                NA
 6: 1001    e2                 3
 7: 1002    e1                 0
 8: 1002    NA                NA
 9: 1002    NA                NA
10: 1002    e2                 2
```

Comment: I suspect you can use `shift(cumsum(!is.na(event)), fill=0L)` or similar for the second part of your `by`. Also, `NA` might not be safe here, better to just stick with integers throughout (`NA_integer_`, `.N-1L`) or numerics.

Comment: @Frank thanks - is `shift` from a package, or part of an update I haven't gotten yet?

Comment: Hm, I think `shift` is available since version 1.9.4. Anyways, it's on the current CRAN version of data.table.

Comment: @Frank 1.9.4 is what I have so it may be the next version - in any case it's time for me to update...

Answer (score 3):

In case you wanted yet another way of achieving the same goal:

```
library(zoo)
DT$group <- rev(na.locf(rev(DT$event))) 
DT[, rowsbefore := lapply(.SD,function(x) {sum(is.na(x))}) , by = .(user,group)]
DT$rowsbefore <- ifelse(is.na(DT$event),NA,DT$rowsbefore)

> DT
    user event group rowsbefore
 1: 1001    NA    e1         NA
 2: 1001    e1    e1          1
 3: 1001    NA    e2         NA
 4: 1001    NA    e2         NA
 5: 1001    NA    e2         NA
 6: 1001    e2    e2          3
 7: 1002    e1    e1          0
 8: 1002    NA    e2         NA
 9: 1002    NA    e2         NA
10: 1002    e2    e2          2
```

If you don't want to replace the NA's and want the group sums, you can just leave out the last line.

*Edit - Per @ Procrastinatus Maximus' comment below, a better way of doing my same solution:*

```
DT[, rowsbefore := sum(is.na(event)), by = .(user, rev(na.locf(rev(event))))
   ][is.na(event), rowsbefore := NA]
```

Comment: Two remarks: (1) When you use a function from another package (in this case `na.locf` from the `zoo` package), it is better to include that information in your answer. (2) Another way of writing up your solution: `DT[, rowsbefore := sum(is.na(event)), by = .(user, rev(na.locf(rev(event))))][is.na(event), rowsbefore := NA]`

Comment: The `$<-` sort of defeats the purpose of the package, as does `ifelse` to modify a subset of rows. One other minor thing: you don't need `{}` unless your function has multiple steps.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments! @Procrastinatus Maximus, you're right that's definitely a better way to do it.